# Segmented Control loading problem in Tab View

Tags: ios, swift, segment

I am trying to implement a segmented control into a view controller like this picture

[image]

In first tab everything is ok but the second tab nothing is displayed

[image: s://i.stack.imgur.com/wnz6Y.jpg]

But I really don't know what is going on.

This is my code in switch between tabs:

```
@IBOutlet weak var NewsView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var VideoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var Newspaper: UIView!

@IBAction func SwitchView(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
        NewsView.alpha = 1
        VideoView.alpha = 0
        Newspaper.alpha = 0
    }else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
        VideoView.alpha = 1
        NewsView.alpha = 0
        Newspaper.alpha = 0
    }else{
        Newspaper.alpha = 1
        NewsView.alpha = 0
        VideoView.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check that wether your views are being hidden from storyboard or not?

Comment: Can you check your view is not blank and proper getter/setting is applied for different uielements.

Comment: Share your table view delegate and data source code.

Answer (score -1):

1. UISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex start with 0, so have you implemented your cases in SwitchView() according to it?
2. Why are you changing alpha value of views, you should hide and unhide the views. If your data are displaying on tableView then change data and reload tableView then no need to add multiple views.
3. You can debug your if-else conditions using breakpoints.

Comment: Why my answer gets a downvote? please explain the reason.

Comment: I don't see the reason to downvote this answer. The questions are reasonable. But you should have asked this questions as a comments to main post, because it is not answering anything.

Comment: @T.Pasichnyk Thank you for your suggestion !!